# Converting to Polar Coordinates: Newton's equations for a particle moving in a plane under the influence of a coulombic potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vectors, physics, polar-coordinates

Convert the following equations to polar coordinates (Newton's equations for a particle moving in a plane under the influence of a coulobic potential). I show what I did below, I am looking for confirmation or for correction.

$\tag{1} m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= \frac{-kx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

$\tag{2} m \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}= \frac{-ky}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

NOTE: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, $\theta = \tan^-1(y/x)$

$\tag{3} m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= \frac{-kx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$
$\tag{4} =\frac{-kr\cos\theta}{r^3}$
$\tag{5} = \frac{-k\cos\theta}{r^2}$

and similarly, $\tag{6} m \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{-k\sin\theta}{r^2}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. You can get proper formating for functions like $\sin$ by using `\sin`. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Why don't you like displayed equations?

Comment: I think the problem requires a couple more steps, since you still have $x$ and $y$ (the second derivative to be precise) in equations (3) and (6)